# A suitable constructor could not be located error

Tags: c#, constructor, controller

I am getting an error on this piece of code and don't have a clue what to do. Can anyone tell me what the problem could be and how to resolve it.

**Error:**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Lic.Controllers.EchipamentController' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
>
> FindApplicableConstructor
>   Stack Query Cookies Headers
>   InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Lic.Controllers.EchipamentController' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

```
namespace Licenta.Controllers
{
    public class EchipamentController:Controller
    {
        private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
        private readonly IEchipamentRepository _echipamentRepository;


        EchipamentController(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, IEchipamentRepository echipamentRepository)
        {
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
            _echipamentRepository = echipamentRepository;           
        }

        public ViewResult List()
        {
            var echipamente = _echipamentRepository.Echipamente;
            return View(echipamente);
        }
    }
}
```

I don t know what to do about that error.

Comment: The constructor is not public.

Comment: what IOC container are you using? have you registered your repositories?

Comment: @MuhammadAli  asp.net mvc . Yes, I registred the repositories

Comment: @madreflection if I declare the constructor public it says that: "Inconsisten accesibility: parameter type "IEchipamentRepository" is less accesible than method "EchipamentController.EchipamentController(ICategoryRepository,IEchipamentRepository)"

Comment: Those interfaces need to be public, too.

Answer (score 3):

add public to this part of your code:

```
public EchipamentController(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, IEchipamentRepository echipamentRepository)
    {
        _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        _echipamentRepository = echipamentRepository;           
    }
```